# "resize the virtual machine and the window" not working

Tags: vmware-vsphere, windows-server-2019

The VMware Remote Console is not resizing the virtual machine to fit the window, even though I have that setting set. Does anyone have any suggestions to make this work?

- VMware Remote Console version 12
- vCenter 6.5
- VM version 10
- VMware Tools is of course installed: v.10.0.9
- launched from Chrome
- guest OS that is having a problem: Windows Server 2019

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IF you still have this issue, you can try setting *Total video memory* under VM Hardware> Video Card to 8 MB.

Comment: Actually, it was set to 4MB and changing that to 8 or 16 added more resolution settings within Windows. 32 seemed to give me even less. But setting it to automatic either completely fixed the issue or got it very close.

Answer (score 0):

vcenter 6.5 is quite old and general support will end this year on October 15th 2022.

Is this on purpose due to hardware restrictions or a restricted enterprise environment?

Which guest OS is affected? Windows or Linux only.

Take look here for Ubuntu.
https://linuxconfig.org/install-vmware-tools-on-ubuntu-20-04-focal-fossa-linux

or here:
https://communities.vmware.com/t5/VMware-Fusion-Discussions/VMware-tools-on-Ubuntu-64-bit-Server-20-04/td-p/2317996

Most systems detect if they are running within a VM and install openvm-tools which is more or less the open source standard today. As far as I know. Vmware tools aren't in development any more for linux because of openvm-tools they come shipped with the distro.

Is it only the window or is the resolution itself not changing. Keep in mind you have to increase vram for VM in case you need higher resolution then 1920x1080.

Comment: Now that you mention it... The guest OS is Windows Server 2019. Server 2008 R2 and Server 2012 R2 seem to work. I don't know about Linux. I'm not worried about that. The resolution I need it to change to is less than 1920x1080.

Comment: maybe a stupid question, but what happen when you change the resolution manually via windows settings?

Comment: otherwise, you can also try to force the resolution manually.
Take a look here:
https://kb.vmware.com/s/article/2058577

Comment: It looks like I can manually change the screen resolution to a few available settings. That helps a bit, but usually, the automatic resize fills the window whatever the window shape or size. I'm trying to figure out why that isn't working, though it does seem now that it is something specific to this version of Windows or maybe even the configuration of this particular VM's guest OS.

Comment: Interestingly, VMwareResolutionSet.exe did nothing.

Comment: Sorry to hear that. Unfortunately, the last time I touched a Windows Server professionally was when 2008 R2 appeared...